# Will my time machine back up go crazy if I changed my password for file vault?

Tags: time-machine, password, filevault

I was thinking of changing my FileVault password to a stronger one - and that got me wondering if that will mess up my time machine.

Can i ask what is the proper way to change the password of your file vault (I am assuming that the password to file vault is the same as the password when you login to your Mac)

Comment: Are you talking about the FV password of your boot drive (Macintosh HD) or of the external disk with TM on it?

Comment: Also, your assumption is wrong: The FV password is not the same as your login password, you just need the login password to unlock the FV password which is stored safely.

Answer (score 1):

No, this doesn’t change things. If Time Machine goes crazy, it’s for other reasons than this.

Now, if you are going to change the encryption keys, the pass phrase to unlock the actual encryption key can be changed trivially but the underlying encryption can be a very lengthy process of decrypting and then encrypting and that can be tedious or worse if you mess up.

You would want to get a thorough dump of your exact hardware, `diskutil list` and possibly more. There are many flavors of filesystem and “file vault” around.